# mysql SELECT to return one of each match

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I'm working on a user registration form that requires address information.

I have a table that has about 1.2 million country/state/city/zip entries that cover the entire world.

Given a country I want to select all the states for that country.  Using the following query and the 'US' as an example query, I get about 49,000 records and I only want 50... one for each state!)

```
SELECT state FROM locales WHERE country='US'
```

The results look like this:

```
Alaska
Alaska
Alaska
Alaska
Alaska
```

Which represents:

```
Akutan, Alaska
Cold Bay, Alaska
False Pass, Alaska
King Cove, Alaska
Sand Point, Alaska
```

I want just one Alaska, one Colorado, one Georgia...

Likewise, given a State I want to select all the cities for that state and given a city, all the zips for that city.

How do I need to write the query to limit this and how do I need to setup the indicies to optimize these queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT will help you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT state FROM locales WHERE country='US'
```

Comment: I gave pawlik the answer because his was first.

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT to restrict  duplicate entries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT state FROM locales WHERE country='US'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT state FROM locales WHERE country='US' LIMIT 50;
```

given a State I want to select all the cities for that state and given a city, all the zips for that city.
Assuming again you want the list for only 50 of them (remove LIMIT 50 if you want all others):
And also replace the fields below with appropriate column names from table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT state, city, zip FROM locales WHERE country='US' LIMIT 50;
```

And if you want list of city and zip for the first 50 states:

```
SELECT state, city, zip FROM locales WHERE country='US' and state in (SELECT DISTINCT state FROM locales WHERE country='US' LIMIT 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this with limit

> SELECT DISTINCT state FROM locales WHERE country='US' LIMIT 0,50

Comment: Shouldn't it be LIMIT 0,50?

Comment: I can't use limit because if someone selects a country with more states I wouldnt get all of the responses.